# Heapsort StackOverflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow, heapsort

I repeatedly get a StackOverflow error at line marked with ** The stack overflows if I try to sort more than 3 numbers but works for arrays of 3 or less, therefore I do not think there is an infinite recursion.
Can someone explain to me why line 246 seems to be the source of the stack overflow?

Thanks

```
    public static void heapSort(double [] a,int node, int index, boolean upcheck){
if(node < 0){

}
else if(node > a.length-index){
}
else if(upcheck){
    if(!testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+1) || !testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+2) ){
            int min = 0;
            if(a[(2*node)+1] > a[(2*node)+2]){
                min = (2*node)+2;
            }
            else{
                min = (2*node)+1;
            }               
            switchHeap(a,node,min);

****************************heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);*********************
        }
    }


else if(node == (a.length-index-1)/2){
    if((2*node)+1 <= a.length-index){
        if(testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+1)){            
        }
        else{
            heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);
        }           
        if((2*node)+2 <= a.length-index){
            if(testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+2)){
            }
            else{
            heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);
            }   
        }
    }
    switchHeap(a,0,a.length-index);
    index++;
    heapSort(a,0,index,false);
}
else{
    if((2*node)+1 <= a.length-index){
        if(testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+1)){            
        }
        else{
            heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);
        }
        heapSort(a,(2*node)+1,index,false);
        if((2*node)+2 <= a.length-index){
            if(testHeap(a,node,(2*node)+2)){
            }
            else{
            heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);
            }   
            heapSort(a,(2*node)+2,index,false);
        }
    }
}

}//heapSort - method
```

Comment: you get StackOverflowError  when your Stack is full (in your case its due to recursion..).

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it is caused but I cannot find any reason why the code should cause a stackoverflow. The stack (I think) is at most as long as the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `StackOverFlowError` due to the recursive call you make in your code. i.e.

```
 static void heapSort(double [] a,int node, int index, boolean upcheck)
```

calls itself recursively. You need to make use of `break;` in this kind of recursive method calls when the work is done

From the documentation,

public class **StackOverflowError**
extends **VirtualMachineError**

*Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.*

Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error) to know more about the error. The accepted answer explains it all

Comment: I thinK I do have a base case in that I check to make sure that the node exists. Do I need something more explicit? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call

```
heapSort(a,(node-1)/2,index,true);
```

the stack will end up having its own set of variables (double[] , int node, int index...) .. this might be causing the problem if your input size is >3 (too much recursion..).

One solution could be to declare only one array which is to be sorted at instance level, not method level and pass just the indices in your functions instead of passing the array.

this might help - http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, however heapsort is meant to be recursive using arrays right?